Most relevant conference for Quantum Computing
I will have to supervise a PhD on Quantum Computing for Optimization problems.
In this respect, I would like to attend to a conference on Quantum Computing, so as to get
a clear view of the most recent research directions and advances, but there are lots of events (see 2024 Conferences). I noticed a few of them :

TQC conference
IEEE Quantum Week
Quantum Technology International Conference

but without any much hindsight about how well it is relevant for my concern which
is more mathematical (solving optimization problems) than physical (qubit physics).
Do you have an idea of the most relevant conference to attend in my case ?

"Do you have an idea of the most relevant conference to attend in my case ?" -- It would help if you would describe your case in more detail.

I am looking for ideas to solve combinatorial optimization problems and/or graph problems with quantum algorithms. These problems can also be multiobjective. I hesitate between TQC and QCE. TQC seems quite theoretical, harder to follow, but it can sometimes bring new ideas, QCE seems more applied according to its 2023 programme. The question is also to meet people, researchers and engineers, with which I could discuss. Then, any comment welcome.

To start with, we have no idea about your background. Nor about how you want to solve those problems - heuristically, provably, ... ?

My background is applied mathematics, I have been working in quantum computing for 4 years now and I understand basic concepts of quantum information and computation, with some practive on IBM online computers.

I am looking both heuristics, like QAOA, and "pure" quantum algorithms.
